We need modify our program. We need to read all .htm files as plain text in folder c:\Untitled and where number 338-232, 34k-33k, dj-34 take

We need modify our program. We need to read many .htm files as plain text in folder c:\Untitled and where number 338-232, 34k-33k, dj-34  take value after  "school-" Wkd and insert value school column in excel file.

we have enter image description here
we need to recieve
enter image description here
file index.php-route=information-news&page=76.htm 
    number 338-232
    school- Wkd

file index.php-route=news&page=5.htm 
    number 34k-33k
    school- kla

file schoodate7.htm
    number dj-34
    school- ece

file  index-904.htm
    number ks-78
    school- kyf

and many other files with different name with .htm extension
Option Explicit
Sub Test1()

  Dim FileSysObj As Object
  Dim FolderObj As Object
  Dim FileColl As Object
  Dim FileObj As Object

  Dim PathSearch As String

  ' This assumes the text files are in the same folder as the workbook holding the macro.
  ' Use PathSearch = "C:\ ..." if you would rather have the files in a different folder.
  PathSearch = ActiveWorkbook.Path

  Set FileSysObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set FolderObj = FileSysObj.getfolder(PathSearch)
  Set FileColl = FolderObj.Files

  For Each FileObj In FileColl
    With FileObj
      If LCase(Right(.Name, 4)) = ".txt" Then
        Debug.Print .Name & "  " & .DateCreated & "  " & .Size & " bytes"
      End If
    End With
  Next

End Sub


The code you show simply lists all txt-files (not htm*) together with the size, so first thing is to replace the check in the If-statement. Then you need code to read the file (make up your mind if you want to read it as html or if you read plain text), find the number and read the school. If you have that, search in your excel for the number and, if found, add the school name into the sheet.

files read in plain text

Okay, then start with "How do I read a text file with VBA" - there a numerous examples here on SO and elsewhere. Currently you don't ask any question and it sounds a little bit as if you expect that someone writes the code for you - that is not how SO works. Create a function that reads the file, create another function that searches for the number and school, create a sub that enters the data into your sheet. If you are stuck, you can ask a question here about that specific problem.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
